# time shifting of either solved tracked camera or 'dynamic paint' baking

Tags: tracking, timeline, dynamic-paint

I am trying to add an animated ship to the real footage of the ocean. I have the solved camera from the footage. I have the ship model. Now I need some wake waves. I can get them using dynamic paint, which has one problem: the waves only start appearing from frame 1, and I need them to be fully generated by this frame.

1. I could not 'pre-bake' waves as dynamic paint does not allow to bake from negative frame numbers.
2. Trying to shift everything to the future shifts all animation, except the camera solution, which still starts playing from frame 1.
3. Trying to shift everything into the future, baking dynamic paint, then shifting back to original time points does not shift the baked data.

What would be my options? Thanks

Comment: Use the frame offset on the footage settings in the video clip editor.

Comment: that offsets the background video, but not the solution for the tracking. Do i need to regenerate solution ?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to bake your camera solve to keyframes then offset it to whatever frame you like.

You do this by selecting the camera with the solve and going into the *Constraints* tab on the right. You'll see a *Camera Solve* constraint. Simply select *Constrain to F-curve*. It'll take a second and then your camera solve will be baked as keyframed animation on the camera which you can do with as you please.